# Proof of Taylor's Theorem: changing dt to d(t-x)

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I am learning a proof of taylor's theorem. This is one of the first steps:

$\int_{x_0}^{x} f'(t) dt$ = $f(x) - f(x_0)$ - FTC

$f(x) = f(x_0) +\int_{x_0}^{x} f'(t) dt$

Now before performing integration by parts, the proof makes the following step:

$\int_{x_0}^{x} f'(t) dt$ = $\int_{x_0}^{x} f'(t) d(t-x)$

Why are we allowed to do this? Is it because $dx$ is an infinitesimal value so when we do this infinitely many times it goes to 0?

Comment: This doesnt look correct. Are you sure the boundaries of the integral stay the same?

Comment: One can change the variable to $s=t-x$ if one likes but the RHS is then $\int_{x-x_0}^{0} f'(s+x) ds$. The notation you've got is crazy.

Comment: @Nurator Yeah, well from the lecture I am watching it says so at least. Then he does integration by parts with $v' = d(t-x)$ and $u = f'(t)$ which then yields taylors theorem when you repeatedly integrate n times with the remainder.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Yeah I think that is what the professor is trying to do, but the notation is really horrible :D What it means is just that you substitute dt with ds=dt-dx and because you just shifted the values, you need to adjust your boundaries to get to the same result again.

Comment: @Nurator I see, thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: @Govind75 But beware: You cant just substitute whatever you like, if you for example substitute $s=x^2$, then you need to be aware of the product rule!